# Roundcube rest api

Tags: api, rest, email, roundcube

is there any REST API for roundcube?
I have this need:

I developed a software where it sends some emails to clients and we need to save the sent mails in the "sent" folder.

I searched a lot and all tutorials say that I have to use the auto_bcc but I need to simulate the client's behavoiur, I mean, when the boss access the "automatic@domain.com" mailbox by using roundcube or another email client, he can see the sent folder and the sent mails (not in the inbox), so I was thinking that if I can connect to roundcube and simulate a mail sending, roundcube will save the mail in the sent folder.

I hope I have explained myself

Thanks